# RXJS - Filter by another observable then groupBy

Tags: filter, rxjs, combinelatest

I have an observable of an array of tasks. I want to filter these tasks by another observable (a text input).

Then I want to group the filtered tasks by an 'entity' property and map that so the result is:

```
{ 'entity': 'a',
  'tasks': [...] },
{ 'entity': 'b',
  'tasks': [...] }
```

This is the closest test i've got:

https://stackblitz.com/edit/rxjs-filter-group

But I can't seem to group them correctly..

Comment: Since you're using `BehaviorSubject` it's a question when you to get the grouped result because `combineLatest` won't complete until all its source Observables complete. You can accumulate tasks for each key but then you'll receive the same group multiple times.

Comment: I actually can’t remember why I was using behaviourSubject, I think because I wanted to initialise the value..? Should I just use a normal observable?

Comment: well if you want to use it as `searchQuery$` you'll need to use a Subject.

Comment: If I change that do you think it should work? Am I doing the groupBy correctly?

Comment: It depends on whether you want it to emit just once for each group or every time you add a new task to a group. You could do it like this for example: https://stackblitz.com/edit/rxjs-filter-group-utze4b?file=app/app.component.ts

Comment: That looks close but the tasks are accumulating every time I type in the input box. I just want that input to filter the tasks

Comment: Is it required that you use `of(this.tasks);`? Working with `from(this.tasks);` might be easier.

Comment: @MichaelB Yes, that's because you're using Subject.

Answer (score 0):

I've updated part of your code, pls, see:

```
const tasks = combineLatest(source,this.searchQuery$).pipe(
        map(([tasks,query]) => {
          return tasks.filter(task => {
            return task.name.toLowerCase().indexOf(query.toLowerCase()) > -1;
          })
        }),
      mergeMap(v => from(v)
        .pipe(
            groupBy(task => task.entity),
            mergeMap(group => group.pipe(toArray()))
        )
      )
    )
```